# Why the same answer?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner.

Why this script gives always 1 as answer? What is the problem?

No matter which month is selected, the answer is always 1.

```
<select id="monthSelect">
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="?" onclick="alert(selectedMonth)"/>

<script>
var e = document.getElementById('monthSelect')
var i = e.selectedIndex;
var selectedMonth = e.options[i].value;
</script>
```

Comment: if you're happy with my answer below, you can accept it.

Comment: How can I "accppt" an answer?

Comment: just go to my answer and in left side right arrow is their just click on it.

Comment: have you got my point..?

Comment: Thanks maxval you correct answer someone else also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution Without Using Function**

```
<select id="monthSelect">
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="?" onclick="alert(monthSelect.selecteIndex);"/>
```

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/09d9bsc0/)

**Solution With function**

```
<select id="monthSelect">
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="?" onclick="getSelectedMonth();"/>
 <script>
 function getSelectedMonth()
 {

var e = document.getElementById('monthSelect')
var i = e.selectedIndex;
var selectedMonth = e.options[i].value;
     alert(selectedMonth);
 }
</scrip>
```

Answer (score 3):

Because your code runs when the side loads, and at this time the selection is 1.

```
<input type="button" value="?" onclick="getSelection()"/>
function getSelection() {      
        var e = document.getElementById('monthSelect')
        var i = e.selectedIndex;
        alert(e.options[i].value); 
    }
```

Your code is fine: http://jsfiddle.net/vrwkpur7/

Answer (score 3):

Problem is with your onclick="alert(selectedMonth)"; as you are not calling any function on it and just put alert. I have correct your code the way you have explained. kindly check below solution. Replace your click event of button with below mentioned click event.

```
<input type="button" value="?" onclick="alert(selectedMonth())"/>
```

Replace your script with below given script and you will have your answer.

```
function selectedMonth(){

   var e = document.getElementById('monthSelect');
        var i = e.selectedIndex;
        return e.options[i].value; 
}
```